# Variable name not accepted in VBA in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a SQL VBA query for updating values in several textboxes on a form on the click of a button.

The query takes the input from the multiple label name captions on the form. So caption of `Label1` will be input for `TextBox1`, `Label2` caption for `Textbox2` etc.

I am trying to pass the label name through a variable to the query. However the following error is returned on the line where value of variable `b` is generated:

> "Microsoft Access can't find the field '&labelname&'referred to in your expression.

My code is below. I want to use a variable so that later I can make it a function to accept the label name and return the recordset value. In this way I will be able to avoid approx. 150 lines of code as I have to update 20 to 25 textboxes with the input from same number of labels.

```
Private Sub Command111_Click()
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim ssql As String
Dim labelname As String
Dim b As String
Set dbs = CurrentDb

'---------------------------------------------------------------------------    ----
labelname = "Label24"
b = [Forms]![Bal_Sheet]![& labelname &].Caption
ssql = "select sum(a.[Bal Fwd]) from Trial_Balance a,Act_Master b where a.GBOBJ = b.object and a.GBSUB = b.sub and b.Cat = " & "'" & b & "'"
Debug.Print ssql
Set rs = dbs.OpenRecordset(ssql, dbOpenDynaset)
[Forms]![Bal_Sheet]![Text1].Value = rs(0)
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
dbs.Close
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expression:

```
b = [Forms]![Bal_Sheet]![& labelname &].Caption
```

Is not concatenating a string, as `[Forms]` and `[Bal_Sheet]` refer to objects.

Instead, you should use:

```
b = Forms("Bal_Sheet").Controls(labelname).Caption
```